# Foundation 6 and ISOTope Column Width Issue

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation, jquery-isotope

Unsure why this isn't working, when I add columns outside of the ISOTope wrapper the column divs work with the Foundation 6 framework, but when adding the columns classes to the divs within the ISOTope the widths no longer work.

http://foundation.zurb.com/
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="">
      <!-- ISO Tope -->
      <div class="filters row">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button data-filter="*">all</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button data-filter=".one">one</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button data-filter=".two">two</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="grid row">
        <div class="grid-item one small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">one</div>
        <div class="grid-item two small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">two</div>
        <div class="grid-item two small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">two</div>
      </div>
      <!-- ISO Tope -->
    </div>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 'Flex Grid' I used Zurb Foundation 6's 'Grid' option. This fixed my issue.